# Conflict between return type and method parameter when return type is 'T' and method parameter consist of wild card

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, erasure

I'm trying to run a code. i and i get two compilation errors:
1.Reference to `System.out.println` is ambiguous (conflict between method that gets char[] and a method that gets a String) 
2.Cap#1 can't converted to T return st.pop()

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stack <Number> stackNumber = new Stack<Number>();
            Test t = new Test();
        t.setMethod(stackNumber,new Integer(3));
        System.out.println(t.getMethod(stackNumber));
    }

    public <T extends Number> void setMethod (Stack<? super Number>st,T t)
    {
     st.add(t);
    }   

    public <T>T getMethod (Stack<? extends Number >st)
    {
        return st.pop();
    } 
}
```

I know that i can change getMethod signature to return Number and program will be compiled successfully but i want to understand why with current signature i'm getting compilation errors?
AFAIK, T without bounds considered as **Object** and a function that declares to return **Object** can return any Object since **Object** is the "Father" of all classes (including Number). Can someone me what i'm dismissing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i want to understand why with current signature i'm getting compilation errors?

The errors are both because `<T>` is determined at the call site.

Looking at compilation error 1:

Java selects the most specifically-applicable method. Any of the `PrintStream.println` methods that take a reference-typed parameter could be selected.

From [JLS 15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

Anything that you can pass to `println(char[])` or `println(String)` can also be passed to `println(Object)`, therefore the former methods are more specific than the latter. As such, these will be selected in preference to `println(Object)`.

However, some things that can be passed to `println(char[])` cannot be passed to `println(String)`, therefore neither of those is more specific than the other, hence the ambiguous method call.

---

Now looking at compilation error 2:

```
public <T>T getMethod (Stack<? extends Number >st)
{
    return st.pop();
}
```

This method must be safe to invoke in all situations. You invoke it like this:

```
System.out.println(t.getMethod(stackNumber));
```

i.e. you treat the result simply like an object. But you could, legally, write this at the call site:

```
String s = t.getMethod(stackNumber);
```

It's hopefully clear that this would fail, because something popped out of a stack containing numbers can't be cast to a `String`.

Because the compiler can't guarantee that it will be called with a "safe" `T`, it's an error.

Comment: Thanks. But i still can't understand it. AFAIK T is erasure by O, so _getMethod_ signature declare that it returns an Object Reference. So How returned typed can be considered as char[] or String. I can't understand, from the way i see the things only Object can be returned from _getMethod_ . If we have a method with the following signature **public Object helpMethod()**, and we will call it from **System.out.println()** everything will work (even if **helpMethod** return a String or anything we want), So what is the different?

Comment: @Eitanos30 the erasure isn't relevant here.

Comment: isn't it replace T with Object?

Comment: @Eitanos30 it is, but at a much later stage in the compilation process. If `getMethod` could only ever return `Object` (or, generally, the erasure of its bound), there would be no point in generics.

Comment: I run again over the example and find two interesting things that i can't understand: 1. From one side println method has conflicts between String and char[] but if i writing System.out.println(t.getMethod(stackNumber).length(), method that exist in String Object i'm getting a compilation error saying that Object class doesn't have length method. It's annoying me since before it said that he has conflict between String and char[],so now when trying to run length method,it suddenly refuses to treat it like String.

Comment: 2 When changing signature of getMethod to <T extends Number> T getMethod(Stack<? extends Number), i still get a compilation  error although now it's seems type safe and you can't assign the returned value into String object as the way you display before? When changing ? to Number it's working but again don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your methods should be using wildcard captures, you have two methods that are generic against some `T`. Like,

```
public <T> void setMethod(Stack<T> st, T t) {
    st.add(t);
}

public <T> T getMethod(Stack<T> st) {
    return st.pop();
}
```

If you want to ensure that `T` must be a `Number` for some reason (I would just use `Number` then), you define it at `T`. Like,

```
public <T extends Number> void setMethod(Stack<T> st, T t) {
    st.add(t);
}

public <T extends Number> T getMethod(Stack<T> st) {
    return st.pop();
}
```

Comment: I said that I know that it can be implemented easily if I will change the signature. But I post the question to get an answer on a specific situation with wild card

Comment: Your "specific situation" is caused by having two unrelated generics: `<T>` and `<? extends Number>` --- you could also write `public <T> T getMethod(Stack<? extends T> st)` and `public <T> void setMethod(Stack<? super T> st, T t)`

Comment: I describe why as I see the erasure way of work, I think it should work. Can you please explain what is wrong in the way i refer to the issue (T is replaced with Object) thus method can return any type). Again I’m not looking for alternative solution, it’s not a task. I’m trying you understand why specific code isn’t working although T is replaced by Object. The time is very late in my country so I may see your response only tomorrow. Thanks